# How to use Observable variable in *ngFor

Tags: angular, rxjs, nativescript

I am using `rxjs` in my nativescript-angular app. 
In my case, I realize a simple animation by setting StackLayout's top with an observable variable `'myTop$'`.  Following codes work well, and the `"StackLayout"` moves as expected :

```
<AbsoluteLayout width="100%" height="100">
  <StackLayout [top]="myTop$ | async" height="30" backgroundColor="#faebd7" width="100%" verticalAlignment="center">
    <Label [text]="'abc'"></Label>
    <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>

public myTop$:Observable<Number> = interval(1000).pipe(map((animationIndex)=>{
          return animationIndex%100; // top range 0->100
      }),share());
```

However, when i put these codes in `*ngFor` for more animations, it seems that nothing happens. For example :

```
  <template *ngFor="let item of objList ; let i=index ">
    <StackLayout [top]="myTop$ | async" height="30" backgroundColor="#faebd7" width="100%" verticalAlignment="center">
      <Label [text]="item.label"></Label>
      <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </template>
```

How can i make it work as expected?

Comment: You probably want to use <ng-container> element instead of <template>

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ng-template` instead of `template` because in angular 6 template is doesn't exists.

example:

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let item of objList ; let i=index ">
    <StackLayout [top]="myTop$ | async" height="30" backgroundColor="#faebd7" width="100%" verticalAlignment="center">
      <Label [text]="item.label"></Label>
      <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help to correct my mistake.

However, it still can not work until i replace 'ng-template' with 'ng-container'.

To exclude the distraction of nativescript，I can also reproduce this issue in a pure angular6 environment.

I know feel about the difference of 'ng-template' and 'ng-container'. Any explanation?